# Modify Urls in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting, webforms

Is there a way to modify all the links to js and css files in my webforms aspx pages without making a call to a helper function?

I want to write a url:
**FROM** ...../Scripts/file.js 
**TO**  ...../Scripts/634969723944992444/file.js

I can do this:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Url.Helper(@"Scripts/file.js")%>"></script>
> ```

where the helper function will include the last modified time of the file as ticks in the url.

Is there an easy way I can modify the urls on all my pages with out using such helper function?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by adding that last modified time?

Comment: I just want to implement auto versioning of js and css files so that browsers always get latest files but still cache the files until they change.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an HTTPModule that would do this. You might also instead putting a time in the path just use querystrings to flag for updates

file.js?v=1
file.js?v=2
file.js?v=3
etc

Comment: If I use query strings, I think browsers will never cache the files.

Comment: Sure they will, until you change the QS value, that's the point of the querystring.

Comment: I am not sure but the query string approach is not being recommended on the web. http://derek.io/blog/2009/auto-versioning-javascript-and-css-files/

Comment: @Harish That guy is wrong. QueryString approach is totally acceptable way to version. If it wasn't, then basically ANY page that uses a QueryString to dynamically load data would be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I think your best option is to abandon your efforts and just use [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).

Aside from bundling (reducing the number of HTTP requests) and minifying (reducing file size), it will also automatically version your bundles (using a querystring), ensuring browsers always get the newest version any time one of your scripts or style sheets change.

If you are using ASP.NET 4.5, you already have access to this functionality. For older versions, you can install via [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/1.0.0).

Other useful links:
[Adding Bundling and Minification to Web Forms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx)